# Invert nested dictionaries in f#    Map<'a,Map<'b,'T>>)  -> Map<'b,Map<'a,'T>> 

Tags: dictionary, f#, nested-sets, higher-order-functions

I have a nested dictionary `Map<'a,Map<'b,'T>>`, so that for a combination of `a*b`, the entry is unique.

In order to precompute efficiently, I would need to invert the keys in a `Map<'b,Map<'a,'T>>`

I have some higher order methods that do the job (`|/>` will apply the operation in a nested sequence `|//>` the same, but 2 levels deep, `|*>` will enumerate the cartesian product of nested sequence), but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, just in case there is beautiful code to share on this one.

```
let reversenmap (x:Map<'a,Map<'b,'T>>) :Map<'b,Map<'a,'T>> = 
      let ret  = x |> Map.toSeq |/> Map.toSeq |*> squash12
      let ret2 = ret |> Seq.groupByn2 (fun (a,b,t) -> b) 
                                      (fun (a,b,t) -> a) |//> Seq.head 
                                                         |//> (fun (a,b,c) -> c)
      ret2 |> Seq.toMapn2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution from @pad is definitely more idiomatic F# than using non-standard operators like `|/>` and `|*>`. I would probably prefer a version that uses sequence expressions instead of `Seq.collect`, which looks like this (the second part is the same as in the version from @pad):

```
let reverse (map: Map<'a,Map<'b,'T>>) = 
  [ for (KeyValue(a, m)) in map do
      for (KeyValue(b, v)) in m do yield b, (a, v) ]
  |> Seq.groupBy fst 
  |> Seq.map (fun (b, ats) -> b, ats |> Seq.map snd |> Map.ofSeq) 
  |> Map.ofSeq
```

Comment: Sequence expression makes enumeration quite natural. having nonstandard operator is indeed an inferior solution here.

Comment: Shouldn't a sequence expression use `seq { ... }` rather than `[ ... ]`? That reminds me, is there any practical difference between `seq { 1..5 }` and `{ 1..5 }`?

Comment: @JoelMueller Did you mean `[ 1..5 ]` rather than `{ 1..5 }`? If so, the difference is in both the resulting type and evaluation method. A `seq { ... }` returns a `seq<'a>` and is evaluated lazily, just like `IEnumerable<T>` (of which it is an alias). `[ ... ]` returns a `'a list` and is immediately evaluated. You can return an infinitely long `seq<'a>`, but you cannot do so with a `'a list`.

Comment: @RyanRiley - No, I meant that `seq { 1..5 }` and `{ 1..5 }` both produce a `seq<int>` containing the same values. I was just wondering if there's a performance advantage to leaving out the `seq` keyword, or a correctness advantage to including it, or if it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JoelMueller: You're able to write `{1..5}` since `..` is range expression. In general cases, only `seq { ... }` is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your intention. But from the signature of your function, we could do something like this:

```
let reverse (map: Map<'a,Map<'b,'T>>) =
    map |> Seq.collect (fun (KeyValue(a, m)) -> 
                                m |> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(b, t)) -> b, (a, t)))
        |> Seq.groupBy fst
        |> Seq.map (fun (b, ats) -> b, ats |> Seq.map snd |> Map.ofSeq)
        |> Map.ofSeq
```

Answer (score 2):

@pad's solution is remarkably similar to what I came up – I guess it just goes to show that with these sorts of problems, you follow your nose doing the only things that could work until you get there.

Alternatively, if you wanted to stick to folds, you could do:

```
let invertNesting ( map : Map<'a, Map<'b, 'c>> ) =
    let foldHelper ( oldState : Map<'b, Map<'a, 'c>> ) ( k1 : 'a ) ( innerMap : Map<'b, 'c> =
        innerMap |> Map.fold (fun tempState k2 v ->
                                  let innerMap' = match ( tempState |> Map.tryFind k2 ) with
                                                  | Some(m) -> m
                                                  | None -> Map.empty
                                  let innerMap'' = innerMap' |> Map.add k1 v
                                  tempState |> Map.add k2 innerMap'' ) oldState
    map |> Map.fold foldHelper Map.empty
```

While @Tomas Petricek's solution is more readable to me, this appears to be about 25% faster.

Comment: very interesting. I remember having to write something similar but wrote it naively in 2 pass.

Comment: how do you time your code btw ? just a regular timer from the Diagnostics namespace ?

Comment: In hindsight, that last comment really didn't give enough detail to be useful. Yes @nicolas, I used the Stopwatch class from the System.Diagnostics namespace for timing, running each test multiple times and averaging their runtimes. This was where the sizes of the inner and outer dictionaries were equal. The speedup also seems to reduce as the sizes of the dictionaries increases – this starts off over twice as fast, but decreases to about 25% faster for the largest sizes I tested.